# WordPress Let Visitor Choose Language

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, multilingual

I am working on a blog that will have both English and Hebrew available. I have got all the Hebrew .mo and .po files in the right directory already. Currently, if I go in the settings section of the administrative area and select Hebrew, everything displays correctly in Hebrew. I'm assuming that what language the site is displayed in is determined from wp_options.WPLANG.

What I would like to do is allow users to choose the language they want, using a parameter passed to the URI (ex. blog.com/?lang=EN or blog.com/?lang=IW). So, all I need to figure out is where the value of WPLANG is actually accessed. I can then simply check for the parameter lang in the URL and have it override whatever the value of WPLANG is provided that the input value is valid, of course.

How can I accomplish this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

WPLANG is set in wp-config.php, so this would be the place to go to change the language globally. Make sure to whitelist the  GET-parameter.

However, there are better solutions to add multi language to WordPress. Have a look at http://wpml.org/.

Comment: Not in the newest versions of Wordpress, apparently.